# Can std::transform() be made exception-ignorant?

Tags: c++, c++20

<sub>This is probably an AB mistake on my part.</sub>

While reading my dataset usually some files are NOT a part of it. I want to be robust against that - to just ignore them, simply log the omission.

But I am in love with exceptions thus `Spectrum read_csv( const fs:path & dataset );` throws.

I want to keep it that way because the `.pdf` and other files my supervisor has embedded into the data structure should stay there.

The following implementation seems elegant. But fails at the first wrong file. A `try/catch` alternative works. But is not as expressive. Can this work somehow while `read_csv()` throws; those exceptions to be at most logged?

```
// How do we make this exception-tolerant?
std::transform( files.cbegin()
              , files.cend()
              , std::back_inserter( ret )
              , read_csv
              );
```

Comment: "*Can this work somehow while read_csv() throws*" That would be a different algorithm, one that knows to catch exceptions and "log" them. That's the exact opposite of being "ignorant" of exceptions.

Comment: @NicolBolas thanks for the excellent point! The heading is what it is because I can live with the algorithm silently ignoring exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not something you should be using exceptions for. If it's expected that `read_csv()` will fail as part of the normal execution of the code (e.g. because the file is missing) and the algorithm should proceed regardless, then exceptions are *not* the correct mechanism to employ here.

By long-standing convention, C++ exceptions are meant to only be used to denote **unexpected failure**. This has two big impacts:

1. Compilers are willing to (and do) implement exceptions in a way that grind the program to a halt if it means that the code can run ever slightly faster when no exception is thrown.
2. Programmers seeing exception handling code will automatically read it as code that runs when the algorithm fails. Diverging from this makes code hard to read and interpret, leading to a large increase in effective complexity.

Because of these two factors, the only thing exception handling code should ever do is rollback the program to the state it was in before the failed operation started. Anything else is almost certainly wrong.

I think you are looking for this (assuming a missing file is the expected error, you can adapt as needed):

```
for(const auto& f: files) {
  if(fs::exists(f)) {
    ret.push_back(read_csv(f));
  }
}
```

The big advantage here is that the failure you *expect*, the file not existing, will be handled cleanly and quickly, whereas failures you don't expect: running out of memory, reading junk data, etc. etc. will still cause an exception that will bubble up and report a failure of the algorithm as a whole.

That being said, your question can still be answered as asked so here it is:

`std::transform` produces something for every element in the input range. Because of that, you need to figure out what get pushed into `ret` when `read_csv()` fails.

The ideal way to handle that would be to use the proposed [std::expected<>](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0323r4.html). If you can't or don't want to use a third-party implementation of the proposal, `std::optional<>` is the closest alternative in the standard library.

If you want to keep `read_csv()` untouched, you would also need a function adapter (let's call it `Maybe`) that swallows exceptions and produces an `expected<>` or `optional<>` on failure. That's not particularly difficult:

```cpp
template<typename F>
struct Maybe {
  F func;

  template<typename... ArgsT>
  auto operator()(ArgsT&&... args) -> expected<decltype(func(std::forward<ArgsT>(args)...)), std::exception_ptr>{
    try {
      return func(std::forward<ArgsT>(args)...);
    }
    catch(...) {
      return unexpected(std::current_exception());
    }
  }
};

...

std::vector<expected<Spectrum, std::exception_ptr>> ret;
std::transform( files.cbegin()
              , files.cend()
              , std::back_inserter( ret )
              , Maybe(read_csv)
              );
```

You could take this further by also adapting the `back_inserter()` so that it pushes the value on success, and does nothing on errors. This way you could go back to producing a `std::vector<Spectrum>`, but that introduces yet more error swallowing, which is just asking for trouble in my book.

[see on godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qP57Tx5b4)

Comment: Ymmm I was *really* trying to stay away from `std::optional` because it adds complexity. Seems I need that complexity after all. Gimme a couple of days to come to terms that `C++` is not `python` and I will accept your answer as thruly solving this problem.

Comment: @Vorac I've rewritten the *answer* in a way that should address that.

Comment: I wouldn’t recommend a separate check for `exists`, since the answer might change before you rely on it.  That doesn’t mean you can’t use something like `expected` if you prefer that to throwing, but you should do so **inside** `read_csv`—which affects the `transform` just as much as the exception does.

Answer (score 0):

You need to come up with your own `transform` taking a functor to call upon exception thrown. This is probably a (really) bad design though as that implementation would need to "catch everything".

You might be in love with exceptions, but this is a scenario where you do *not* want to use them. After all, you're expecting some file to be missing. You wouldn't write

```
void add(int lhs, int rhs)
{
 throw lhs + rhs; // DON'T!!!
}

int main ()
{
  try {
    add(40, 2);
  } catch (int result) {
    std::cout << "answer: " << result << ".\n";
  }
}
```